# Best way to move object from one collection to other in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongojs

How to move object from one collection to other ? What is the easiest and safest way to do it? I was trying with that:

```
app.post('/doneList/:id',function(req, res){
    var id = mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    var oneTodo;
    db.todoList.findOne({_id: id},function(err,docs){
        db.doneList.insert(docs,function(err,doc){
            res.json(doc);
        });

    }); 
    db.todoList.remove({_id: id});
});
```

but it crashes when I try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally need to work "inside" the callbacks, but [`.findAndModify()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) is probably a lot cleaner here as well:

```
app.post('/doneList/:id',function(req, res){
    var id = mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    var oneTodo;
    db.todoList.findAndModify(
        {
            "query": { "_id": id },
            "remove": true
        },
        function(err,doc) {
            if (doc) {
                db.doneList.insert(doc,function(err,doc){
                    // respond moved
                });
            } else {
               // respond was not found
        }
    );
```

That way the document is "removed" from the collection at the same time as the content is retrieved. Of course you only `.insert()` when an actual document was matched and "inside" the callback from the initial `.findAndModify()` operation.

It's one less call to the database and one less level of nesting.

Comment: Thanks, that was thing I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: Nevermind this answer. Go with Blakes Seven's answer, its better.

It crashes because you are removing before you could insert within the callback.

Give this a shot:

```
app.post('/doneList/:id',function(req, res){
    var id = mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id);
    var oneTodo;
    db.todoList.findOne({_id: id},function(err,docs){
        db.doneList.insert(docs,function(err,doc){
            res.json(doc);
            db.todoList.remove({_id: id});
        });
    }); 
});
```